# .NET Core 2.0 & Angular Initial app build fails - Can't find python followed by JavaScript Runtime Error

Tags: python, node.js, angularjs, asp.net-core, npm

I am on VS 2017 and .NET Core 2 on Win 7.
Tried creating a fresh app in .NET Core 2.0 and Angular using [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Running latest versions of node and npm :

```
node -v > v10.1.0
npm -v > v6.0.1
```

According to the instructions, I went ahead to build the application and got

`Can't find Python`

I checked env variables the path has python. Not sure why it can't find it.

The build seems to have "half worked" and got some dependencies sorted.  The second go around building the app gave me a JavaScript Runtime Error .. which I think is due to crappy first build job.

I also tried running "npm install" in the ClientApp folder and gave the same errors, `Can't find python`.

Any help would be appreciated !

**Build Log**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>TestApp -> C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\TestApp.dll
1>v10.1.0
1>Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes...
1>
1>> uws@9.14.0 install C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\uws
1>> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0
1>
1>
1>> node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
1>> node scripts/install.js
1>
1>Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node
1>Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node":
1>
1>HTTP error 404 Not Found
1>
1>Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
1>      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
1>
1>      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
1>
1>or configure npm proxy via
1>
1>      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
1>
1>> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
1>> node lib/post_install.js
1>
1>
1>> node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
1>> node scripts/build.js
1>
1>Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
1>gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
1>gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1>gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
1>gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
1>gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
1>gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
1>gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
1>gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
1>gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
1>gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
1>gyp info using node@10.1.0 | win32 | x64
1>gyp verb command rebuild []
1>gyp verb command clean []
1>gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
1>gyp verb command configure []
```

**Starts to fail ...**

```
1>gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
1>EXEC : gyp verb `which` failed error : not found: python2
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
1>EXEC : gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { error : not found: python2
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
1>gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)',
1>gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
1>gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
1>EXEC : gyp verb `which` failed error : not found: python
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
1>EXEC : gyp verb `which` failed  python { error : not found: python
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
1>gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
1>gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)',
1>gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
1>gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
1>gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
1>gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
1>gyp ERR! configure error
1>EXEC : gyp ERR! stack error : Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
1>gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
1>gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
1>gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
1>gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:165:21)
1>gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
1>gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mohammadrauf\\Desktop\\Angular_Projects\\TestApp\\ClientApp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
1>gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass
1>gyp ERR! node -v v10.1.0
1>gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
1>gyp ERR! not ok
1>EXEC : Build failed with error code: 1
1>npm WARN rollback Rolling back y18n@3.2.1 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\mohammadrauf\Desktop\Angular_Projects\TestApp\ClientApp\node_modules\yargs\node_modules'
1>npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 (node_modules\node-sass):
1>npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
1>npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
1>
1>added 1218 packages from 1231 contributors in 93.516s
1>[!] 33 vulnerabilities found [6676 packages audited]
1>    Severity: 3 Low | 21 Moderate | 9 High
1>    Run `npm audit` for more detail
```

Comment: Please post complete error message

Comment: Have you imported python modules ? https://pythonnet.github.io/

Comment: edited w/build log

Answer (score 8):

I ran this command:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

Running this command installed Python 2.7 and the project compiled successfully.

Comment: I am surprised that this still exists in .net core 3.1 + Angular CLI 9.1.9 + Node 14.4.0 + Win32 64x (Windows 10)

Answer (score 7):

`node-gyp` has dependency on `Python2.x`. [Install `Python` in your system](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2714/).

Checkout the required dependency from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp)

Comment: weird. it was working with 2.7, and then it wasn't. `brew install python2` got me going.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

and then try:

```
dotnet run
```

It was right for me